# php - gd - How can I load a jpg, delete its background, place it over another jpg and save it?

Tags: php, transparency, gd

I'm using **php**'s **gd** library and the task I'm trying to accomplish is this:

1. Load `background.jpg` which is just a gradient background.
2. Load `product.jpg`, which has a white background.
3. Delete background color from `product.jpg`
4. Place edited `product.jpg` over `background.jpg`
5. And save as **jpg**

So far I'm able:

1. to open `background.jpg` and place `product.jpg` over it without removing background (easy one)
2. to open `product.jpg` and delete background color and save it as **png**

The last thing I tried, without any luck is this:

1. load `background.jpg`
2. load `product_image.php`, which loads `product.jpg`, deletes background and returns a **png**, with transparent background.
3. place it over `background.jpg`

Is it possible to achieve this, or I have to save it as **png** first and then convert it to **jpg**?

I would appreciate if anyone could point my in the right direction. Which are the **key commands** I **must** use to accomplish this?

Comment: Please paste some code so that i can see where you are making the final image

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible, and my guess is you're going to have to use PHP's Imagick:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Here's one function that might be what you're looking for:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-painttransparentimage.php